# How to pass system properites in comand line to scala 3 executable

Tags: scala, command-line, system-properties, scala-3

With scala 2 it was possible to pass system properties in the command line using `-D<propname>=<propvalue>` like in the following example:

```
$scala -Dpath.to.folder=/opt/myfolder
```

Scala v3 does not accept -D in the command line anymore:

```
$ scala -Dpath.to.folder=/opt/myfolder
bad option '-Dpath.to.folder=/opt/myfolder' was ignored
Welcome to Scala 3.1.0 (11.0.9.1, Java OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM).
```

One possible solution (workaround) is to pass the properties through the environment:

```
$ env SYS_PROPS="-Dpath.to.folder=/opt/myfolder" scala
Welcome to Scala 3.1.0 (11.0.9.1, Java OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> println(System.getenv().get("SYS_PROPS"))
-Dpath.to.folder=/opt/myfolder

scala>
```

How is it possible to pass system properties in the command line of scala 3 executables?
`scala --help` does not provide any useful info. Actually in scala 3.1.0 `scala --help` and `scalac --help` print the same message in the stdout.

Comment: It looks like a scala 3.1 bug

Comment: It is actually a bug to be fixed in scala 3.1: https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/issues/14005